# Why is an absolute value in the answer to this question?

Tags: exponentiation, absolute-value

This was the explanation to the answer on a college algebra CLEP test:
Since $(64a^6)^{1/6} = (64^{1/6})\times(a^6)^{1/6} = 2 \times|a| = 2|a|$

Why is $a$ an absolute value? $a^6$ will equal a positive number regardless if $a$ is positive or negative, so I don't see the purpose of taking the absolute value of $a$.

Comment: Why not just plug in $a = -1$ and see what happens?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! That is because any positive number has two (real) roots of even order which have opposite signs, and by definition, the notation $A^ {1/6} $ is used for the *positive* root of the positive number $A$. Here $A=a^6$, but the sign of $a$ is not given.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself:
"$a^6$  will equal a positive number regardless if $a$ is positive or negative".

So then you can always take the sixth root, regardless of whether $a$ was positive or negative. That sixth root is a positive number of the same magnitude as $a$.

So how do you write that in a formula?